# How can I submit a form from frame 1 to frame 2 using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, frameset

I'm doing an assessment that requires the use of frames and php and am currently having trouble trying to submit a form from the left frame to the right without it refreshing the whole frameset

At the moment I can search for the product and have it display the correct information, but I would like to be able to search from the left frame and display it on the right.

*Update*

I do want the product page to refresh once I post the form, just not the whole frameset.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <FRAMESET COLS="25%,75%">
        <FRAME name="left" SRC="menu.php">
        <FRAMESET ROWS="50%,50%">
            <FRAME name="topright" SRC="product.php">
            <FRAME name="bottomright" SRC="cart.php">
        </FRAMESET>
    </FRAMESET>
</html>
```

menu.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <center>
        <form action="product.php" target="topright" method="post">
          Enter Product ID: <br>
          <input type="text" name="id"><br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
      </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting the target attribute on the form is the correct way to do this. So how exactly is this not working then?

Comment: If you want to update data on a webpage without refreshing it you will need to use ajax to pull the data from the server and then JS to update it on the second iframe. However, you should reconsider the use of iframe in this case. The same functionality can be achieved with a simple html and css layout (maybe bootstrap if you are into it)

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified that i dont want the whole frameset to update but I dont care if the single frames refresh if that makes sense. All i want is to submit a form from one frame and display it on the second frame. Would what i want be possible or should i implement the ajax method?